# date_query empty results with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, get-posts, date-query

I am trying to use `get_posts` to return data between certain dates but I always get an empty result even though there is a lot of data. This is for a custom post type.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'bookings',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => '2022-01-01',
                'before' => '2022-06-01',
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        )
    );

$data = get_posts($args);
die(var_dump($data));
```

I also tried something like the below to get a specific date but still an empty array:

```
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => 2022,
            'month' => 01,
            'day'   => 21,
        ),
    )
```

Comment: does it work without date_query?

Comment: So, I tested it further up the functions file and it worked, with the date query. For some reason when it is lower down in the functions file it doesn't work. Hmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're trying to get all posts in the first half of 2022, as opposed to the first 6 days of 2022, then you need to be clearer with your before and after dates.

`date_query` uses `strtotime` behind the scenes, which will interpret your dates as Jan 1 to Jan 6. You need to either change the dates to the American format of YYYY-DD-MM, or be more specific by [using arrays to express your dates](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters) instead.

Comment: I have edited my question with something else I tried. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sure - but I would drop the leading zero (use `1`, not `01`) as I'm not sure that's valid in this context.